# TinyMce - How to set editor height below 50px when using autoresize pluggin

Tags: javascript, tinymce-4

How can I set `tinymce` editor height to 36px, when I set this the iframe height becomes 67px. If I set height above 100 it works fine. I need the editor to auto resize with typing or paste
My code is like this:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea,
    plugins: ["paste autoresize"],
    height : '40px',
    icon: false, menubar: false, statusbar: false, toolbar: false, autoresize_bottom_margin: 10, object_resizing: false,
    paste_as_text: true, force_br_newlines: true,autoresize_max_height : "300px", 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working by setting the init options like

`tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea,
    plugins: ["paste autoresize"],
    autoresize_bottom_margin: 2,
    autoresize_min_height: 36,
    autoresize_max_height: 300,
    icon: false, menubar: false, statusbar: false, toolbar: false, autoresize_bottom_margin: 10, object_resizing: false,
    paste_as_text: true, force_br_newlines: true,
});`

Answer (score 1):

you can use `min_height` configuration setting.
In your case the code should be:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: ["paste autoresize"],
    min_height: 10,
    height : 30,
    icon: false,
    menubar: false,
    statusbar: false,
    toolbar: false,
    autoresize_bottom_margin: 10,
    object_resizing: false,
    paste_as_text: true,
    force_br_newlines: true,
    autoresize_max_height : "300px"
});
```

as you said, with `autoresize` plugin it does not work. maybe this is a problem of `autoresize` plugin. anyway there is another option `autoresize_min_height : 30` which I tested but as it seems this does not work either.

Comment: it is not setting to 30

Comment: @beginner I think it could be problem of one of the plugins `autoresize`. remove it and test again. I in my testing removed it and it is working. See the edit.

Comment: yes, it is resized to 30, but when i shift+enter it not increasing the height

Comment: thanks for ur reply, when we set like this it does not auto resizing, i need to resize the editor from 30 to 300 on shift+enter or word-wrap

Comment: @TechJS Indeed you are correct, removing this made it work, pity that the plugin overrides the default height value.